# How do I open a div then close it again with a changing text button

Tags: jquery

How can I expand a hidden on page load div from a link saying "Show info" but when the link has been clicked and the information was displaying the link text would change to "Hide Info" and the box would then close the opposite way it opened when "Hide Info" link was clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use `.slideUp()`,`.slideDown()` and `.toggle()` functions of jQuery. Here is the demo: http://harryjoy.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/how-to-create-drop-downup-login-and-follow-me-box/

Comment: There will also be approximately 1 million jQuery plugins to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quite easy:

```
$("#infoToggler").click(function()
{
    if($(this).html() == "Show info")
    {
        $(this).html("Hide info");
        $("#infoBox").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).html("Show info");
        $("#infoBox").hide();
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/aFzG9/

Answer (score 1):

The 'easiest' way would be to use jQuery and employ the [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods.

For updating the link text, simply use something like

```
$("#linkId").text('Hide Info');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="ShowHideInfo">Show Info</a>
<div id="Info" style="display:none">info</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ShowHideInfo").click(function(){
        $("#Info").toggle(function(){
            $("#ShowHideInfo").text($(this).is(":visible")?"Hide Info":"Show Info");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this example which you can easily run and tweak to meet what you want.
You'll need to download the jquery file yourself though.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){


  $("#bttn").click(function() {

   var str = $("#bttn").text();

    if(str == "Show Info")
    {   
     $("#content").show();
     $("#bttn").text("Hide Info");

     }

     else {

     $("#content").hide();
     $("#bttn").text("Show Info");
     }
  });

  });




</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content" style="display:none;width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid gray;padding:2px"> I am a nice little div.</div>

<a href="#" id="bttn">Show Info</a>

</body>

</html>
```